# asp.net LDAP query not returning all results

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm using LDAP commands via c# to add and remove groups to an active directory organizational unit, but I'm having a problem when I query the AD after changes have been made.

Basically, when the user hits the button to add the group, the code adds the group and then re-binds the data to a listview in order to update the list of groups that the user sees.

The problem is that the newly added group isn't showing up all the time.  It's not an issue of the code to add the group didn't work, or that the code to list the groups doesn't work, it appears that there is just a delay before the domain shows the group as existing.

My theory is that the domain controllers have not finished synching together, and it just takes time to get that done before it will list the updated groups.

So my question(s) are, is my theory correct, or is there some kind of cacheing going on, and if there is indeed a delay, is there a way to accomodate this delay?

I can force the application to just wait, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have multiple DC's in your network? If you happen to add a group on DC1, then it might take a few minutes (up to 15) to get replicated to the other DC's ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that changes have not yet been replicated. LDAP clients must never search for an entry that was just modified or added because of eventual consistency. The correct procedure for an LDAP client that makes a change to an entry is to attach the post-read request control to the modify request. The post-read response will contain the state of the entry after the modification was complete.

A professional quality LDAP proxy server with server affinity can be placed between clients and servers to ensure that client operations are always sent to the same server (usually for a configurable period of time). This negates the effect of eventual consistency. For more information, see the article [post-read request control](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/post-read-controls.html).

Comment: Thanks.  Since it confirms my suspicion about the replication, I just specified a domain controller in my ldap queries rather than just the domain itself.